# Retrieve count (total) from non-default REST API

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I would like to query my server for this URL `http://localhost:1337/api/posts/count?category=technology` using Ember. I'm using the default RESTAdapter like this:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  coalesceFindRequests: true,
  namespace: 'api',
)};
```

The Post model looks like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  permalink: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
});

export default Post;
```

How do I make such a request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have at least two ways to achieve that when you don't have a control over your backend. Otherwise, you can still use the RESTful API (see the last section of my answer).

## Override buildURL

The first one is to use the existing `RESTAdapter` functionalities and only override the `buildURL` method:

```
var PostAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',

  buildURL: function(type, id, record) {
    var originalUrl = this._super(type, id, record);
    if (this._isCount(type, id, record))  { // _isCount is your custom method
      return originalUrl + '/count';
    }
    return originalUrl;
  }
});
```

where in the `_isCount` method you decide (according to `record` property for example) if it's what you want. And then, you can pass the params using the store:

```
this.store.find('post', {
  category: technology
});
```

## Override findQuery

The second way is to override the whole `findQuery` method. You can either use the aforementioned `DS.RESTAdapter` or use just `DS.Adapter`. The code would look as the following:

```
var PostAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',

  findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
    // url be built smarter, I left it for readability
    var url = '/api/posts/count';

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Ember.$.getJSON(url, query).then(function(data) {
        Ember.run(null, resolve, data);
      }, function(jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.then = null;
        Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
      });
    });
  },

});
```

and you use the store as in the previous example as well:

```
this.store.find('post', {
  category: technology
});
```

## Obtaining 'count' from `meta`

If you have a complete control on your backend, you can leverage the power of [metadata](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/handling-metadata/).

The server response then would be:

```
// GET /api/posts/:id
{
  "post": {
    "id": "my-id",
    "title": "My title",
    "permalink": "My permalink",
    "body": "My body"
  },

  "meta": {
    "total": 100
  }
}
```

and then you can obtain all the meta information from:

```
this.store.metadataFor("post");
```

Similarly, you can use this approach when getting all the posts from `/api/posts`.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the extensive help. I've got complete control over how the server supplies the data. Is there a better way to provide the count via JSON?

Comment: Thanks for the metadata-example. What if metadata is different (different post-counts for different post-categories) ?

Comment: I think you can still use `this.store.find('post', { category: technology })` and then, on the backend side, respond with a correct `meta.total` according to  the query param you've passed (`category`).

Comment: the response could be also: `{ meta: { total: 100, technology1: 50 } }`